# httpd.conf updated but i cannot see results

Tags: linux, apache

I'm trying to change site IP and path in httpd.conf    usr/local/apache/conf

for example:

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
DocumentRoot /home/mypath/public_html
```

However my site is still not working, it doesn't go to the right path and I cannot see the index.html page. As I understand the server virtual host should be configured with IP and path for domain.  Why I do not see the wanted results, i just want the website to show the index.html ?

What to do?

Comment: try asking on serverfault. And say what "not working" means.

Comment: Is 111.111.111.111 just an example?

Comment: Have you restarted your web server?

Comment: @AmitGarg how to restart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting using the command:

```
service httpd restart
```